# Selenium - Extracting the onclick event target url within a script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, onclick

Let's say I have a HTML page with the following element:

```
<script>
    function change_url(){
        window.location.href='http://www.google.com/';
    }
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="change_url()">
     Go to Google
</button>
```

Is there a way to get the target URL of the button without having the browser visit the URL ?

Thank you.

Comment: It is unclear from your question how you would `get the target URL of the button without having the browser visit the URL` as `Selenium` mocks the `User Actions`. Perhaps form `web-scraping` perspective you must consider using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: As the link is the result of a javascript interaction, I can't use beautifulsoup for this. What I could do is click on the element and return to the previous URL if the domain changed... But that's not ideal. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well you  are asking for a way `without having the browser` and `Selenium` is not that way. Hence `Beautifulsoup` is the `Answer` :)

Comment: Just wondering if it would be possible, if someone has a way to do this. Just like you could get the href attribute of an element. Perhaps there is way to get the "result of cliking" on a button, without actually clicking on it.

Comment: @MaximeDeBruyn did you figure out a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

As per your question heading it wouldn't be possible with **`Selenium`** to `get the target URL of the button without having the browser visit the URL` as **`Selenium`** mocks the **User Interactions** initiating a `Browser Instance`.

Once you initiate the browser, to get the target URL which is **`http://www.google.com/`** you can extract the page source and use **`split()`** function as per the following code block :

```
driver.get('https://www.your_url.co.in')
page_source = driver.page_source
text_part = page_source.split("window.location.href='")
my_url = text_part[1].split("';")
print(my_url[0])
```